# Colorbar slows down plot

Tags: matlab, plot, colorbar

I am plotting many images in a loop on the same axes to make a video. Unfortunately the presence of a colorbar makes the loop a whole lot more slow. This happens even though I've "frozen" the colorbar using `caxis('manual')`.

Why? I suppose there still may be listeners slowing the whole thing down, but it's really bad. Having frozen the colorbar there are no should be no calculations involved with it.

Here's a demo that illustrates some of the workings of the colorbar, mainly with the aim of freezing it. There's no loop in the following.

```
close all
figure(1);
C = gallery('randcorr',10);
ih = imagesc(1*C);
ch = colorbar;
% The colorbar disappears...
ih = imagesc(2*C);
% Must hold plot in order for it not to disappear
hold on
ch = colorbar;
% Now, even though it doesn't disappear, it still changes!
ih = imagesc(3*C);
% Even if we use a lower lever function
set(ih,'CData',4*C);
% We must do this to freeze the colorbar
caxis('manual')
set(ih,'CData',5*C);
ih = imagesc(6*C);
% That worked!
```

Comment: I don't see a loop. Can you show an example of a loop where this occurs so we can be sure that we're looking at the same thing and can see which particular functions might be the cause in your case?

Answer (score 3):

This is more interesting than I expected. I have no answer, but a series of examples demonstrating some non-answers. Maybe someone smarter than me will have better luck.

Example, with a colorbar:

```
figure;
C = gallery('randcorr',10);
ih = imagesc(1*C);
ch = colorbar;
caxis([-2 2])
tic; 
for ix = 1:100
    set(ih,'CData',gallery('randcorr',10));
    drawnow
end
toc;  %2.7 seconds
```

And without a colorbar

```
figure;
C = gallery('randcorr',10);
ih = imagesc(1*C);

caxis([-2 2])    
tic; 
for ix = 1:100
    set(ih,'CData',gallery('randcorr',10));
    drawnow
end
toc;  %0.67 seconds
```

What caused the change from 2.7 to 0.67 seconds?

A colorbar is really just a special sort of axis, so maybe the problem is having more than 1 interesting axis in the figure

```
figure;
subplot(2,1,1)
C = gallery('randcorr',10);
ih = imagesc(1*C);
subplot(2,1,2)
C = gallery('randcorr',10);
ih2 = imagesc(1*C);

caxis([-2 2])    
tic; 
for ix = 1:100
    set(ih,'CData',gallery('randcorr',10));
    drawnow
end
toc;  %0.87 seconds (consistently slower,  but not enough)
```

Maybe the property linking is causing the slow down

```
figure;
subplot(2,1,1)
C = gallery('randcorr',10);
ih = imagesc(1*C);
subplot(2,1,2)
C = gallery('randcorr',10);
ih2 = imagesc(1*C);
link = linkprop(get(gcf,'children'), 'CLim');

caxis([-2 2])    
tic; 
for ix = 1:100
    set(ih,'CData',gallery('randcorr',10));
    drawnow
end
toc;  %0.88 seconds (pretty much the same as above)
```

Looking at the default colorbar, it has a lot of color detail, maybe the problem is simply the number of colors which need to be rendered.

```
figure;
subplot(2,1,1)
C = gallery('randcorr',10);
ih = imagesc(1*C);
subplot(2,1,2)
ih2 = imagesc(repmat(linspace(-2,2,200), 10,1));

caxis([-2 2])    
tic; 
for ix = 1:100
    set(ih,'CData',gallery('randcorr',10));
    drawnow
end
toc;  %0.96 seconds (slower, but still not the 2.7 second colorbar case)
```

Comment: I can't replicate your timings at all, particularly the cases where it gets much faster (Mac OS X 10.9, R2013a). There is only a slight difference – less that 10%. And of course we're guessing at at what the OP is doing in their own loop.

Comment: Interesting. FWIW, I am running Windows 7, R2012b. I kind of suspect that the video card and settings may be just as relevant.  ... Kind of a pain to dig into that through.

Comment: I get similar results as in this answer. Colorbar is at least 2x slower than the others... OS X 10.9, R2013b.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Pursuit for investigation the issue further, which seems too deep to resolve properly.

Having not found a good standard solution, I resorted to making my own colorbars in separate subplots. These are then left untouched during the loop. To make your own colorbars I recommend using subplot(1,5,1:4) for the main plot, and subplot(1,5,5) for the colorbar. Then you just plot a linspace of the caxis using imagesc again to make the colorbar. Supply y ticks, remove x ticks.